# webkit sticky footer menu

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, css, mozilla

I want to create a sticky footer menu for a web application (-webkit/-moz). Check out the screenshot. Blue area border of the iphone, red area representing content, gray area at bottom is footer.
[image]

Screen 1:
Start screen. Full content with a sticky footer at bottom of window, I can do this via position: fixed.

Screen 2:  Actual Required Behavior
If the content of page is scrolled down the footer should remained stick to the bottom of the window. Thats what I need.

Screen 3: Current behavior with position: fixed
This is the current behavior, if i scroll page the whole thing is moved up including the sticky footer at bottom.

I want a web application, behavior similar to ipod library. Fixed menu at bottom and scroll-able content above it. Any solution?

Comment: Is the fixed footer inside any other elements? If it is, try putting it right in the body, with `position: fixed; bottom: 0;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would require to take multiple absolute position layers to achieve this. Use window's resize event adjust these layers. We have done same this in our website [www.maniartech.com](http://www.maniartech.com).